# Suggest DOM event when coding Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to show code hints like: onclick, onblur..... Is there any extention that can help me do that?
I tried installing tabnice,JavaScript (ES6) code snippets but look at the picture below, I typed .oncl but vs code doesn't suggest onclick as expected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX2cC.png)

Comment: [Don't use onclick, onblur, etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers). They're legacy functions that unfortunately cannot be removed from JS, but that you should _not_ be using anymore. Use the 20+ year old [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) that replaced them, instead.

Comment: treat the above question as rhetorical. that dup-target _does_ answer this question. you don't need an extension. you need to understand the type system and help guide it.

Comment: Thanks for edit my question, I found the answer in your edit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using addEventListener instead of onClick. It should look like this.

```
x.addEventListener("/* Event to listen for eg: click */", /* function to be run when the event happen */)

x.addEventListener("click", function listener(){
 console.log("listening")
})
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. it's just code review. see the answer I posted in the dup-target.